# Using the W3C GeoLocation API's watchPosition function

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I cannot work out how to watch a user's location using the W3C GeoLocation API. What's the easiest way? All I want is an update of the user's latitude and longitude.

Comment: If you already have some code for us to look at please provide it.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been using this in a project, I worked it out using [Ben Nadel's blogpost](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2023-Geocoding-A-User-s-Location-Using-Javascript-s-GeoLocation-API.htm) and the API itself.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){

    // These variables update every time the location changes
    var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;

}, function(error){
    // You can detect the reason and alert it; I chose not to.   
    alert('We could not get your location');
},{
    // It'll stop looking after an hour. Enabling high accuracy tells it to use GPS if it's available  
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 600000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
});
```

Hope this helps!