# Add location marker like Google Maps Mobile App onto JS v3 GoogleMap

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've optimized a page for mobile devices that shows a google map.

I'd like to display the user's location in the same way the the Android and Iphone GoogleMaps application does (i.e. blue triangle with larger circle indicating margin of error).  I'd also like this marker's location to change and update as the user moves.

Is this something I can implement in a map created using the Javascript API or is this only possible on mobile apps for Android and Iphone?

I am comfortable obtaining geolocation as from the link below.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geolocation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.  You'll need to get the geolocation (per the link that you have set up).  You'll want to use the `watchPosition` method with the geolocation API.

[Using the W3C GeoLocation API's watchPosition function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248555/using-the-w3c-geolocation-apis-watchposition-function)

From there, every time the positon changes, you can make a call to the Maps API and update the map center and/or location of the marker that represents the users current location.